# I saw many moving stars moving at high speed and disappearing at the middle. What could it have been?

Tags: identify-this-object

Time : 6:30 to 1:00 P.M.

Location :  8°52'42"N 38°48'49"E

Date : October 28, 2020

I saw stars moving one after another and there were many of them. After moving some distance they vanished one by one. it was not a shooting star as they move at high speeds. I am sure it is not satellite because they were many and they were quite fast.

Comment: The latest cluster of Starlink satellites moving into Earth's shadow?

Comment: @AyushBhatt thoughtful edit! I wrote [Are there Starlink train-finding websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48032/12102) to see if we could start identifying these. It would not be hard to write a Python script using [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) to download the [satcat entries](https://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/) for Starlink and flag the passages of satellite trains over given locations. If you like Python and Astronomy then it's a perfect match.